# How to plot list of numbers in gnuplot using shell script

Tags: shell, plot, gnuplot

I have a list of values, for example, as follows

```
 list = ( 12 51 2 7 9 30)
```

How can I plot the list using gnuplot in a shell script?

Comment: How is your data available? In a text file or do you want to type the data in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be the following:

```
gnuplot -p -e "array Data[6] = [12, 51, 2, 7, 9, 30]; plot Data w lp pt 7"
```

Unfortunately, you have define the size of the array beforehand (here: 6).
Although, there should be a way using the special filename `'-'` with inline data (see `help special-filenames`). You can add data afterwards in a gnuplot script or type the data in the gnuplot console and end data with `e`. However, I haven't found the syntax to do this as a one-liner.

**Result**: with default terminal (in my case 'wxt')

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to provide the size of the array since version 5.4. From the release notes: "Array size can be implicit if an initializer is present, e.g. `array A = [1,2,3]`"